# Modify all the strings between two sets of rows

Tags: r, string, rows, between

I am currently working with several datasets containing information about the 5570 brazilian municipalities and I often have to merge them by name. But it happens that several names are repeated across states (which are named in the UF: rows). An example of a dataset is:

```
   <chr>       
 1 UF: Alagoas      
 2 IBATEGUARA  
 3 MARAGOGI    
 4 MESSIAS     
 5 PENEDO      
 6 PORTO CALVO 
 7 UF: Amazonas
 8 APUI        
 9 HUMAITA     
10 MANAQUIRI
```

And what I want would be something to distinguish each municipality by which state it is:

```
   <chr>       
 1 UF: Alagoas      
 2 IBATEGUARA (AL)
 3 MARAGOGI (AL) 
 4 MESSIAS (AL)     
 5 PENEDO (AL)      
 6 PORTO CALVO (AL)
 7 UF: Amazonas
 8 APUI (AM)      
 9 HUMAITA (AM)    
10 MANAQUIRI (AM)
```

With this I would have a unique name to each locality. I have tried using `mutate_at` and inputing the rows between each state identifier, but I would like a simpler way to do this across different datasets. How can I modify all the strings between two sets of rows?

Comment: Yes, they would be something like AL for Alagoas and AM for Amazonas and so on. What I want is to specifically add this abbreviation to every municipality's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to create a grouping column based on the occurrence of 'UF' string

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(col1, '^UF:\\s+')) %>%
    mutate(newcol = toupper(str_extract(first(col1), '(?<=UF: )\\w{2}')),
            col1 = case_when(row_number() > 1 
                 ~ sprintf('%s (%s)', col1, newcol), TRUE ~ col1)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(col1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating the new code in a new label. This approach uses `tidyverse` functions and `base R`:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("UF: Alagoas", "IBATEGUARA", "MARAGOGI", 
"MESSIAS", "PENEDO", "PORTO CALVO", "UF: Amazonas", "APUI", "HUMAITA", 
"MANAQUIRI")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

The code:

We detect the patterns `UF`:

```
#Detect UF
i1 <- df$V1[which(grepl('UF:',df$V1))]
i2 <- which(grepl('UF:',df$V1))
```

Now, we create and format labels:

```
#Format labels
labs <- gsub('UF: ','',i1,fixed = T)
labs <- toupper(substr(labs,1,2))
```

We assign a new variable to save the labels with indexing:

```
#Create a new var and assign
df$Label <- NA
df$Label[i2] <- labs
```

We complete the variable:

```
#Now fill
df %>% fill(Label) -> df
```

We prepare the variable to remove the `UF` rows:

```
#Remove UF
df$Label[i2] <- NA
```

Finally, we filter the dataset:

```
#Format dataset
df <- df[!is.na(df$Label),]
```

The output:

```
            V1 Label
2   IBATEGUARA    AL
3     MARAGOGI    AL
4      MESSIAS    AL
5       PENEDO    AL
6  PORTO CALVO    AL
8         APUI    AM
9      HUMAITA    AM
10   MANAQUIRI    AM
```